# react native : How to display the table inside the accordion In my example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, accordion

In my example I present an accordion separately and a table separately and I wanted to know how I present the table within the accordion.

this is the accordion that i want put inside it the table as in the example below :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion } from "native-base";
const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "**I WANT PUT HERE THE TABLE**" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "BO" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "MO" }
];
export default class AccordionHeaderContentStyleExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}
            headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#b7daf8" }}
            contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ddecf8" }}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

this is the table that i want put inside the "content" of the "First Element" accordion above :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
 
export default class ExampleOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['Head', 'Head2', 'Head3', 'Head4'],
      tableData: [
        ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['1', '2', '3', '456\n789'],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      ]
    }
  }
 
  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          <Rows data={state.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
        </Table>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
  text: { margin: 6 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help

```
import ExampleOne from "../components/ExampleOne";

// ExampleOne is the component that should be rendered inside content of dataArray
renderExampleOne = () => {
  return <ExampleOne />;
};

const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: this.renderExampleOne() },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "BO" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "MO" }
];

renderContent(item: ArrayContent) {
   return item.content;
}


<Accordion
   dataArray={dataArray}
   headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#b7daf8" }}
   contentStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ddecf8" }}
   renderContent={this.renderContent}
/>
```

Comment: its not good the way of the import of the component because i need put there data from hooks, so i need the table in same page

Comment: You can do this https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2557

Comment: if i send my way so u can try help me ?

Comment: Sure will try to make it